# how to disable upgrade HTTP/0.9, HTTP/1.0,or HTTP/1.1 connection to HTTP/2

Tags: nginx, http2

i added http2 into my nginx serverblock config as shown below

```
server {
        listen 80 http2;
        listen [::]:80 http2;
```

Would like to ask does Nginx h2c (http2 clear text) upgrade a HTTP/0.9, HTTP/1.0,or HTTP/1.1 connection to HTTP/2 ?

Is the connection upgrade disabled when I insert http2 into my nginx config ?